# How can I fix overlapping wires (dots on both sides of a component) on Altium SCH?

Tags: altium

After I replaced a capacitor on several schematic sheets with "Design Item ID", the connections became overlapping like attached (with dots on both ends of the cap).  What's the easiest way to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Probably delete and re-draw the offending wire segments.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things come to mind:

1. If you have **Components Cut Wires** enabled in Preferences > Schematic > General, you could control-click-drag the capacitor (to disconnect it from anything attached), then drag it back into place. With that option enabled, it will remove any wires that are "under" the component when placed.
2. You could simply remove the portions of wire using the key command <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>. (Edit > Break Wire). This may or may not be useful depending on your [Break Wire preferences](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/schematic-preferences#!break_wire).